# How to get rid of transparent image background nested in ImageBackground - react native

Tags: css, react-native, background-color, transparent

I want to place a couple of planet images inside my background but can't remove the transparent background (the checker's pattern). As can be seen:
[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClYYl.png)

I tried to set the css with:  **backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"**  as can be seen:

```
const MainScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundContainer} source={bgImage}>
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/images/red_planet.png")}
          style={styles.image}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.btnLogin}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("sounds")}
        >
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>SOUNDS</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  }
```

UPDATE: both the image and the background image are .png:
[code snipet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXtqn.png)

Is this something I have to do with photoshop or it can be done with CSS?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: You need a `.png` image. It ain't a css problem. You could also use a circular div for this, but simpler is better.

Comment: Can you show me full link to red_planet.png ?

Comment: Process image through this [tool](https://www.remove.bg/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is around image editing and not coding.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO both the image and the background are .png and I still can see the gray-white grid as image background

Comment: @Fakt309 what do you mean full link?
red_planet.png is an image that sits in the project assets folder and I get as so: 
<Image
            source={require("../assets/images/red_planet.png")}
            style={styles.red}
          />

Comment: If your picture opens in the operating system with the same squares at the back, then the problem is in the photo and not in the code.

Comment: @Viktor yes your image is png, but that grid is part of the image. You need to remove it with an image editor software f.e: photoshop

Comment: thanks for the answers. photoshop it is then